# Jordan Form of a 3x3 Matrix with an eigenvalue of multiplicity 3...

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&2&3\\
1&3&3\\
-1&-2&-2
\end{bmatrix}
.
$$

Find the Jordan Form, $J$, of this matrix, and an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $A = QJQ^{-1}$. I have already found the Jordan Form of this matrix, that is,

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

The part that I am confused about is finding the matrix $Q$. I know that the columns of $Q$ will consist of the eigenvectors, and generalized eigenvectors of $A - \lambda I$. The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$p_A(\lambda) = \lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 1 = (\lambda - 1)^3.$$

I have found the eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$ to be

$$v = (-5, 1, 1).$$

However, $(A - I)^2 = 0$, so I am confused on how to find the generalized eigenvectors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has been asked many times at this site, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236159/finding-jordan-canonical-form-for-3x3-matrix), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291433/finding-the-jordan-form-of-a-3-times-3-matrix), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734049/finding-jordan-basis-of-a-matrix-3x3), etc. I think, you could follow the steps and explanations given at this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You should proceed backwards:

- take any vector $u_3$ in $\ker(A-I)^2\smallsetminus\ker(A-I)$, i.e. any  vector in $\mathbf R^3$ which does not satisfy the equation $\;x+2y+3z=0$, e.g. $u_3=(1,0,0)$.
- set $u_2=(A-I)u_3$. This vector is an eigenvector.
- complete $u_2$ with a linearly independent vector $u_1$, so as to obtain a basis of the eigenspace.